# Sitecore 7 + Lucene: Query-Time Boosting: how?

Tags: lucene, sitecore, sitecore7

for items of a certain template, our users can indicate that the item should be shown on top of the list.

For this, we have added a field in the index "ShowOnTop".

Now when searching for items of this template (to build the list page), we would like to have these "ShowOnTop" items to effectively be returned on top of the other items.

This field however should not affect other site search (general search).

We think this could be possible by applying Query-Time Boosting to these documents. But, how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To do boosting at query-time simply use Boost(value) method (using a search predicate as it sounds like you might be doing some advanced searching where added flexibility of predicates might come in handy) -

```
var queryPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResult>();
queryPredicate = queryPredicate.And(i =>
                            i.Headline.Contains(model.Query).Boost(50));
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way would be to apply a Sort based on that field, something along the lines of:

```
Sort sort = new Sort(new SortField("ShowOnTop", SortField.STRING, true), true);
var hits = new SearchHits(context.Searcher.Search(query, sort));
```

You could also add it as a heavily boosted optional query term, something along the lines of, and make the rest of the query is required (as a whole), like:

```
ShowOnTop:true^10000 +(the rest of the query)
```

With a large enough boost factor, those terms should always come up first unless there is a really drastic difference in relevance.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is creating a rule under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Indexing and Search/...` that filters on your ShowOnTop field (I used a checkbox and compared the value with `1`) and adjust the boost by 99999999

You can either add this rule as Global Rule or you can add it as Item rule and assign the rule from within the item.

Good luck!